# can't store new data

Tags: httprequest, laravel-5

I have there database tables: assignees, tickets and categories. In ticket table, assignee_id and category_id is foreign key. I wrote some request controller. And I tried to save new ticket request to database. But when I test my app, it show below errors:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laraapi`.`tickets`, CONSTRAINT `tickets_assignee_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`assignee_id`) REFERENCES `assignees` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `tickets` (`title`, `content`, `priority`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (testtitle, test content, 1, 2016-07-08 16:06:16, 2016-07-08 16:06:16))
```

Here is some codes block of my ticket controller (App\Http\Controllers\TicketCtrl.php)

```
public function store(TicketRequest $request)
    {
        $values = $request->all();

        Ticket::create($values);

        response()->json(['message'=>'Done!']);
    }
```

Here is codes block of my ticket request (App\Http\Requests\TicketRequest.php)

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
            'priority' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function response(array $errors)
    {
        return response()->json(['message'=> 'You should put title, content and priority', 'code'=> 422], 422);
    }

}
```

In ticket request, I changed authorize to TRUE because I didn't setup any authorization service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the solution to fix .

I add `\DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');` before create and `\DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');` after create. But I don't know detail advantages and disadvantages of using SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS .